# Is it possible to estimate the correlation between an equity and its IV, purely from its IV skew?

Tags: correlation, implied-volatility

If we know the options Implied Volatility (IV) skew for an equity, is it possible to calculate the probability of the equity moving, given a move in the IV?

We can define IV skew as the difference between IV at delta 0.25 compared to IV at delta 0.75.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The skew alone is not enough.  You can see this by noting the one-to-one correspondence between volatility skew and terminal probability distributions, which is independent of price and volatility dynamics.  (See my answer at [How to derive the implied probability distribution from B-S volatilities?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/qqplot-of-returns-from-implied-vols-as-opposed-to-historic-vols/1676#1676) for a derivation of that dependence)

Now, if you choose a non-Black-Scholes model (such as the Heston model) and calibrate it, then you can use that model to compute, say, the maximum likelihood equity price given a certain level of implied volatility.

Comment: Very interesting. We have developed a model that can accurately predict IV in all of the market regimes we have tested it in, back to 2002. Would you be interested in collaborating to produce a  method of using this same equation to predict the underlying? Preliminary results show that this is definitely possible with SPX/VIX.