# What is the risk neutral density and how is it estimated?

Tags: risk-neutral-measure

I don't understand the words "risk-neutral density". Please explain what it is, and how it can be estimated in practice.

---

My **guess** would be that we have an underlying probability space $(\Omega, P)$. We are interested in the equivalent martingale measure $Q$, i.e. the space $(\Omega, Q)$.

For every stock price $S_t$, we wish to determine the $Q$-distribution. The risk-neutral density, if it exists, is the *density* $\phi$ of $S_t$ with respect to the *Lebesque measure*, i.e. we can write for some fixed $t$, $$E^Q S_t = \int \phi \cdot s \ ds.$$

Is this guess correct? If so, how do we estimate $\phi$ from stock prices?

Comment: Check out [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29524/breeden-litzenberger-formula-for-risk-neutral-densities), [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/how-to-derive-the-implied-probability-distribution-from-b-s-volatilities?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this other](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24918/obtaining-risk-neutral-probability-from-option-prices?noredirect=1&lq=1) questions.

Comment: As Daneel Olivaw mentions with the "what" and the "how" in your questions have already been answered several times on this site. Please do some research next time.