# Breeden-Litzenberger formula for risk-neutral densities

Tags: options, calibration, density

Based on this topic:
[How to derive the implied probability distribution from B-S volatilities?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/how-to-derive-the-implied-probability-distribution-from-b-s-volatilities)

I am trying to implement the Breeden-Litzenberger formula to compute the market implied risk-neutral densities for the S&P 500 for some quoting dates. The steps that I take are as follows:

*Step 1*: Extract the call_strikes `c_strikes` for a given maturity T and the
    corresponding market prices `css`.

*Step 2*: Once I have the strikes and market prices, I compute the implied volatilities via the function `ImplieVolatilities.m` I'm 100% sure that this function works.

*Step 3:* Next, I interpolate the implied volatility curve by making use of the Matlab command `interp1`. Now, the vector `xq` is the strikes grid and the vector `vq`the corresponding interpolated implied volatilities.

*Step 4*: Since I have to volatility curve, I can compute the market implied density:
\begin{align}
f(K) &= e^{rT} \frac{\partial^2 C(K,T)}{\partial K^2} \\
&\approx e^{rT} \frac{C(K+\Delta_K,T)-2C(K,T)+C(K-\Delta_K, T)}{(\Delta_K)^2}
\end{align}
where $\Delta_K = 0.2$ is the strike grid size. I only show the core part of the Matlab program:

```
c_strikes = Call_r_strikes(find(imp_vols > 0));
css = Call_r_prices(find(imp_vols > 0)); 

impvolss = ImpliedVolatilities(S,c_strikes,r,q,Time,0,css); %implied      volatilities
 xq = (min(c_strikes):0.2:max(c_strikes)); %grid of strikes
vq = interp1(c_strikes,impvolss,xq); %interpolatd values %interpolated implied volatilities 

    f = zeros(1,length(xq)); %risk-neutral density
function [f] = secondDerivativeNonUniformMesh(x, y)
dx = diff(x); %grid size (uniform)
dxp = dx(2:end);
d2k = dxp.^2; %squared grid size
f = (1./d2k).*(y(1:end-2)-2*y(2:end-1)+y(3:end)); 
end

figure(2)
plot(xq,f);
```

Note: `blsprice` is an intern Matlab function so that one should definitely work. 
This is the risk-neutral pdf for the interior points:

[image]

**The data** The following table shows the option data (left column: strikes, middle: market prices and right column: implied volatilities):

```
                   650                     387.5                  0.337024
                   700                    346.45                  0.325662
                   750                     306.8                  0.313846
                   800                    268.95                  0.302428
                   850                    232.85                  0.290759
                   900                    199.15                  0.279979
                   950                     168.1                  0.270041
                   975                     153.7                  0.265506
                  1000                     139.9                  0.260885
                  1025                    126.15                  0.255063
                  1050                     112.9                  0.248928
                  1075                     100.7                  0.243514
                  1100                     89.45                  0.238585
                  1125                     79.25                  0.234326
                  1150                      69.7                  0.229944
                  1175                      60.8                   0.22543
                  1200                      52.8                  0.221322
                  1225                      45.8                   0.21791
                  1250                      39.6                   0.21486
                  1275                      33.9                   0.21154
                  1300                     28.85                  0.208372
                  1325                      24.4                  0.205328
                  1350                      20.6                  0.202698
                  1375                      17.3                  0.200198
                  1400                     13.35                  0.193611
                  1450                      9.25                  0.190194
                  1500                      6.55                  0.188604
                  1550                       4.2                  0.184105
                  1600                      2.65                  0.180255
                  1650                     1.675                  0.177356
                  1700                     1.125                  0.176491
                  1800                     0.575                  0.177828
```

$T = 1.6329$ is the time to maturity, $r = 0.009779$ the risk-free rate and $q = 0.02208$ the dividend yield. The spot price $S = 1036.2$.

**Computation of the risk-free rate and dividend yield via Put-Call parity**
$r$ is the risk-free rate corresponding to maturity $T$ and $q$ is the dividend yield. In the numerical implementation, we derive $r$ and $q$ by again making use of the Put-Call parity. To that end, we assume the following linear relationship:
$$f(K) = \alpha K-\beta,$$
where $\alpha = e^{-rT}$ and $-e^{-qT}S(0) = \beta$, and $f(K) = P(K,T)-C(K,T)$. The constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are then computed by carrying out a linear regression. Consequently, the risk-free rate $r$ and dividend yield $q$ are then given by
\begin{align}
r &= \frac{1}{T}\ln\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right), \nonumber \\
q &= \frac{1}{T} \ln \left(\frac{-S(0)}{\beta}\right). \nonumber
\end{align}

Comment: Could you please tell me where you got the data from. I am struggling to find market price on historical options, given a strike price

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume that for approximating the second derivative of the call price $C (K,T) $ at the bounds of the strike domain (see first 2 "if" cases of the last for loop of your code) you tried to set up *boundary conditions*.

On the right bound, your approximation $C(K+\Delta K, T) \approx 0$ could make sense for $K \to \infty$ or at least big enough.

On the left bound however, $C(K-\Delta K, T)$ cannot be approximated by zero, since call price is almost only intrinsic value for low strikes. Instead of zero, you could use the discounted difference of the forward price minus the strike, $C(K-\Delta K, T) \approx B(0,T)(F (0,T)-K)$, if $K \to 0$ or at least small enough.

This explains why you observe a strange behaviour on the LHS (with a negative pdf), while I guess that if you zoom in or remove that outlier you should be OK.

As a first step, you could simply compute the pdf for interior points xq(2:end-1) (i.e. last case of your for loop) and check what it gives.

**[Edit]**

Looking more closely, it seems like your input prices allow for static arbitrage opportunities, more specifically butterfly arbitrage. As such you cannot expect to obtain a reasonable pdf.

Although it is far from perfect, maybe the script below will help. In it, I try to look for the strikes leading to arbitrage, and discard the corresponding inputs to obtain what a so-called "clean" pdf. This is a non-parametric approach. As discussed in the comments, using a parametric approach (e.g. fitting the vol smile using an arb free representation), will produce an even smoother pdf.

```
function [ ] = someBreedenLitzenbergerCode( )

% Get data and interpolate
[K, C, ~] = getData();
dk = 0.5;
k = min(K):dk:max(K);
c = interp1(K, C, k, 'spline');

% Notifying vertical arbitrage opportunities
dC = diff(C);
if any(dC > 0)
    warning('Input call prices allow for arbtirage (vert. spread)'); 
end

% Notifying and dealing with butterfly arbitrage opportunities
f = secondDerivativeNonUniformMesh(k, c);
idxkArb = find(f<0)+1;                                     
if ~isempty(idxkArb)
    warning('Input call prices allow for arbitrage (butterfly)');
end

% Finding indices of input strikes/prices leading to arb
idxKArb = [];
for i = 1:length(idxkArb)
    idxHi = find(K>=k(idxkArb(i)),1,'first');
    idxLo = find(K<=k(idxkArb(i)),1,'last');
    idxKArb = [idxKArb, idxHi, idxLo];
end
idxKArb = unique(idxKArb);
disp('Strikes leading to butterfly arbitrages');
disp(K(idxKArb));

% Cleaning inputs and calculating pdf
K_clean = K; K_clean(idxKArb) = [];
C_clean = C; C_clean(idxKArb) = [];
k_clean = min(K_clean):dk:max(K_clean);
c_clean = interp1(K_clean, C_clean, k_clean, 'spline');
f_clean = secondDerivativeNonUniformMesh(k_clean, c_clean);

% Plotting results
if ishandle(1), clf(1); end;
figure(1);
subplot(221);
plot(K, C, 'x'); hold on;
plot(k, c, 'r-');
plot(k(idxkArb), c(idxkArb), 'rd');
grid on;
title('Original call prices, C(K)');
subplot(222);
plot(k(2:end-1), f); hold on;
plot(k(idxkArb),f(idxkArb-1), 'rd');
grid on;
title('Pdf, \phi(K)');
subplot(223);
plot(k_clean, c_clean); hold on; 
lh.Box = 'off';
grid on;
title('Clean call prices, C(K)');
subplot(224);
plot(k_clean(2:end-1), f_clean); hold on;
a = ksr(k_clean(2:end-1), f_clean, 60); % Available at Matlab Central
plot(a.x, a.f, 'k-');
lh = legend('FD','FD + Smoothing');
lh.Box = 'Off';
grid on;
title('Pdf, \phi(K)'); 

end

function d2y_dx2 = secondDerivativeNonUniformMesh(x, y)

dx = diff(x);
dxp = dx(2:end);
dxm = dx(1:end-1);
d2k = dxp.*dxm;
d2kp = dxp.*(dxm+dxp);
d2km = dxm.*(dxm+dxp);
d2y_dx2 =  2./d2km .* y(1:end-2) - 2./d2k .*y(2:end-1) + 2./d2kp .*y(3:end);

end

function [strikes, prices, volatilities] = getData()

mat = [650        387.5      0.33702
      700       346.45      0.32566
      750        306.8      0.31385
      800       268.95      0.30243
      850       232.85      0.29076
      900       199.15      0.27998
      950        168.1      0.27004
      975        153.7      0.26551
     1000        139.9      0.26088
     1025       126.15      0.25506
     1050        112.9      0.24893
     1075        100.7      0.24351
     1100        89.45      0.23858
     1125        79.25      0.23433
     1150         69.7      0.22994
     1175         60.8      0.22543
     1200         52.8      0.22132
     1225         45.8      0.21791
     1250         39.6      0.21486
     1275         33.9      0.21154
     1300        28.85      0.20837
     1325         24.4      0.20533
     1350         20.6       0.2027
     1375         17.3       0.2002
     1400        13.35      0.19361
     1450         9.25      0.19019
     1500         6.55       0.1886
     1550          4.2       0.1841
     1600         2.65      0.18025
     1650        1.675      0.17736
     1700        1.125      0.17649
     1800        0.575      0.17783];
 strikes = mat(:,1);
 prices = mat(:,2);
 volatilities = mat(:,3);

end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Quantuple. I have tried to plot the density for the interior points, but I think it is still a rough approximation and not exactly what I had in mind. I like the finite difference method because it is simple. However, the boundary conditions are annoying. In the book of Jim Gatheral, *the Volatility Surface*, he proposes a kind of analytical approach to find the risk neutral density by implicitly giving a formula for the volatility curve. However, that is quite messy as well. Since this is not the major concern of my paper, I would like to have a simple approach.

Comment: Personally, I also perform a "closed-form" estimation of the pdf by relying on a parametric representation of the vol smile (usually Gatheral's SVI). The reason is that, although simple, finite difference is prone to numerical errors, with a lot of instabilities depending on your mesh size (+ adapt formulas if the mesh is not uniform) and your interpolation scheme (the manner in which you interpolate implied volatilities in your case for instance). Not to mention that careless interpolation / wrong boundary conditions can lead to arbitrage opportunities, even if there are none in the raw data.

Comment: Maybe you could post your new results so someone can help you further?

Comment: If it is not too much work, I will definitely take a look into the SVI parameterization by Gatheral. It is indeed true that I did not paid much attention to the nature of the interpolation etc. because I just needed a rough estimate. Thanks!

Comment: I had some to time to do some research about the SVI model. However, due to lack of time, it is too complicated to implement. So I guess I am going to use the second order finite difference scheme. I have EDITED my post with the risk neutral density for the interior grid points. I'm not sure how to interpret this result.

Comment: @user39039 there is definitely something wrong: you end up with negative pdf => butterfly arbitrage opportunities. Can you post the plot of the call prices against striked and implied volatilities against strikes please?

Comment: For me it's also weird that you use an implied volatilities vector `imp_vols` to retrieve strikes `c_strikes` and prices `css` which you in turn use to get implied volatiles `impvolss` again... why don't you use `imp_vols` directly instead of computing `impvolss`? also where do the values of `r` and `q` come from? If they are not obtained from call put parity (I.e. they do not yield the right forward price), you'll definitely introduce arbitrage. Also, you should compute all the call prices once and for all instead of each time within the loop. Finally are you sure that `c_strikes` is sorted?

Comment: First, thanks for your continuous help. Second, I have edited my topic by including the dataset that I use. The left column are the strikes, second column the market call option prices and third the implied volatilities (the ones from imp_vols as you suggested, this is indeed easier). Using this data, I exactly run my script and obtain the density in my original post.

Comment: @user39039 thanks I'll have a look at it tomorrow. Could you maybe post the implied volatilities with a higher precision?

Comment: Also could you give the time to expiry $T$ the spot value $S_0$ and how you compute $r$ and $q$?

Comment: I have included everything you have asked. Let me know if there is still something missing. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, I see, your problem comes from the fact that your input call prices allow for static arbitrage opportunities (here butterfly arbitrage => negative probabilities). Let me write an example of script to show you one of the many possible ways to deal with them.

Comment: Looks as though your interpolation is not smooth at the strikes. This makes the second derivative of your option price discontinuous. You should use a cubic or higher polynomial or other spline to interpolate your implied volatility curve.

Comment: @user39039, I've edited my answer. The finite difference approximation I used may also be useful to you as it is a more general version that works with non uniform grids.

Comment: @Dom you are right, but actually the fly arb is already present in the raw data so the actual interpolation method won't change lots.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Quantuple. I guess, I'm too unexperienced in financial engineering to saw that one coming. I'll analyze the code and see what I obtain. Really helpful!

Comment: @user39039, no problem. You can further smooth the results using kernels if you like. I've edited the code snippet + figure to show this.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I had in mind. Now I can compare the market implied risk neutral densities with those obtained from the calibration procedures. Do you have, btw, a good source/paper where I can read more about this statistical arbitrage in relation to the implied risk neutral densities?

Comment: It's not statistical but static arbitrage. It's covered in any good textbook. Just look for butterfly arbitrage, calendar arbitrage and vertical spread arbitrage.

Comment: @Quantuple : In the mean time I have red a few papers to better understand the arbitrages occurring from interpolating the volatility curve. So, now I see why the strikes that cause $f<0$ have to be excluded. However, I do not entirely understand why you have done the construction with 'idxhlo' and 'idxLhi'. I understand that it is to clean those strikes that are quoted that cause the arbitrage due to the smoothing. But why do you implement it like that?

Comment: @user39039. That's why I said the code was far from perfect. Basically when I detect an *interpolated strike* $k$ (small k) where there is fly arb, I remove the 2 *original strikes* $K$ (big k) which led to this interpolated strike. It should be possible to do a smarter correction, this is "brute force" if you like.

Comment: I like the brute force approach so that is no problem. So if I understand it correctly: since we have interpolated the strikes, we walk over all the indices corresponding with the interpolated strikes and see which ones give a negative density. Then, we detect which original strikes (big $K$) are above and below these indices and eventually remove them as they introduce arbitrage?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I tried to implement indeed.