# complete python code to calculate risk neutral density from option prices

Tags: risk-neutral-measure

bAsic python code to implement  Litzenberger formula for risk-neutral probabilities implied by option prices.
Use S&P 500 option prices whose strike intervals are typically 5 points apart
use at and out of the money option prices

Comment: A simple google search leads to [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29524/breeden-litzenberger-formula-for-risk-neutral-densities)

Comment: I don't want to use Breeden-Litzenberger formula anymore.  I want to use Bondarenko convolution method. I found code but the code does not seem to include the ranges of the variable outside listed strikes n the minimization problem And those are critical.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the codes you found?